# 2 transaction in same address - Please help

Tags: blockchain.info

Sent my  btc address 3 days ago for a payment to one of my customer  he didnt respond or paid . next day i provided the  same address to my another customer for a payment which he sent. Now today i received an email from my 1st customer that he paid the amount to same address that i provided 3 days ago . Please anyone here who can help me to recover the funds . I will lose my job & anyone here who is kind enough to help to simple tips .

https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/15iga5K4hLMjDFox24mvjjuak2g3cKVtMK

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit confusing to understand. Please reword a bit for a better understanding for others.

Comment: Still confused. Which wallet are you using? Most wallets would just show that as your balance. I'm wondering if you copied an address that is not yours thinking it is yours and gave it to the customers. Thus getting the payments there would not add to your actual wallet. Please clarify as your question is still confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The address you linked has received two payments, if you control the private keys for that address then you have nothing to worry about, those coins are in your control.

Generally, it is not best practices to reuse an address, as it is very bad for your privacy (and, potentially the privacy of your customers). However, in terms of being able to spend the coins later, there is no technical issue with receiving more than one payment to an address.

You should be able to spend the two UTXOs as normal.

Comment: Thank you sir but how can i find private keys on blockchain wallet & re - use the coin - Help please please please

Comment: As a user, you shouldn't need to worry about private keys in this situation, the software will handle it. If you received the coins to an address generated by your blockchain.info wallet, then you should simply be able to spend the coins using your blockchain.info wallet. No extra steps. BUT, if you received the coins to a 'watch-only' address that was added to the blockchain.info wallet, then that wallet will not have the private keys. In that case, you will need to find the wallet/person that controls the private key to that address. There is no way to 'recover' a private key otherwise.